# Using atomic<bool> to wait on two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, atomic

Let's say I have a simple pool class:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
class pool
{
 public:
   pool(std::vector<T> data) : 
     data_(data),
     thread_1_finished(false),
     thread_2_finished(false)
     {}
   void thread_1(Iterator, Iterator);
   void thread_2(Iterator, Iterator);
   void thread_3_method_1();
   void thread_3_method_2();
   void do_it();
 private:   
   std::vector<T> data_;
   std::mutex mut_;
   std::condition_variable data_cond_;
   threadsafe_queue<int> data_queue_;

   std::atomic<bool> thread_1_finished;
   std::atomic<bool> thread_2_finished;
};
```

The `thread_3` needs to wait on the completion of `thread_1` and `thread_2`, which is done by calling `notify_all` on the condition_variable `data_cond`, after setting thread_1_finished to true. Both thread_1, thread_2 do it this way:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
  void pool<Iterator, T>::thread_1(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
   sort_block<Iterator, T>  s;
   s(first, last);
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut_);
   thread_1_finished = true;
   data_cond_.notify_all();
   fprintf(stderr, "thread 1 finished.\n");
}
```

Now this doesn't compile:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
  void pool<Iterator, T>::thread_3_method_1()
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut_);
   data_cond_.wait(lk,
           [this]()->bool
            {
              return (thread_1_finished && thread_2_finished);
           });
}
```

In fact I get:

```
charles@ely:~/src/C/sandbox/waiting_on_two_threads$ make
makedepend -pobj/ -Y/dev/null -I. test.cpp 2>makedepend.err
g++ -c -g -w -std=c++11 -I. -I/home/charles/src/C/include -I/home/charles/src/C    test.cpp -o obj/test.o
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:126:38: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccU4V5nL.out file, please attach this to your     bugreport.
make: *** [obj/test.o] Error 1
```

This compiles:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>                                                             
  void pool<Iterator, T>::thread_3_method_1()                                                 
{                                                                                                   
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut_);                                                           
   data_cond_.wait(lk,                                                                              
               [this]()->bool                                                                   
                   {                                                                                
                      return thread_1_finished;                                                     
                   });                                                                              
   data_cond_.wait(lk,                                                                              
               [this]()->bool                                                                   
                   {                                                                                
                      return     thread_2_finished;                                                     
                  });                                                                              

}
```

Why is this? I guess the second method will accomplish the same thing, considering the unique_lock, but I still don't get it.

```
charles@ely:~$ uname -a
Linux ely 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

charles@ely:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.0-7ubuntu3) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: It is just a compiler bug, either update it or
as error says: "Please submit a full bug report" to your compiler vendor.

Comment: If you access them with the mutex held (and you realistically have to if you don't want to lose notifications to the condition variable) the bools do not need to be atomic.

Comment: I orginally used `bool` for both, then tested the atomic versions as I wasn't completely sure. Is there any case in which I may not hold a mutex when accessing them? Don't know - isn't it safer making them atomic?